# VS-NodeJSTools testing, how to debug into tests

Tags: visual-studio

VS NodeJs tools allows for running NodeJS scripts within VS debugger (very cool!)

However, I have setup a tests-only type of project (using Mocha) and wanted to run tests in debug within VS

How does one debug a mocha tests only nodejs project within the VS nodejs tools environment?

**Note, I need 1500+ rep to add a neccesary vs-nodejstools tag to this post**

Answer (score 0):

Answer is the VS-Nodejstools default nodejs tools project creates the **app.js** file which is what gets invoked when you hit `F5`

Call mocha directly by manipulating the environment a little in your **app.js**

```
process.argv = ['mocha'];
require('mocha/bin/_mocha');
```

Now you can Debug into your mocha tests!